# Is the set of rational numbers recursive?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory

My question is expressed by means of Quine's definition of rational numbers in Set Theory and its Logic,  chapters 17 and 18. 
Let pairing of natural numbers be represented as by his definition 17.1 $x;y=_{def}x+(x+y)^2$, let as by 18.1 $x/y=_{def}  \{z;w|z,w\in\mathbf{N}\wedge x\cdot w > y\cdot z \}$ and as in 18.10 let $\mathbf{Q}=_{def}\{x/y|x, y\in\mathbf{N}\wedge y\neq 0 \}$. Is $\mathbf{Q}$ $\Delta_1$, or just $\Sigma_1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this definition, each rational number is a set of natural numbers, so you're asking about the status of a **set of sets** of natural numbers. Every $\Sigma_1^0$ subset of $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is open in the usual topology (the product topology on $2^{\mathcal N}$), but this version of $\mathbb Q$ is not open.  Given any rational $x/y$ and given any finite subset $F\subseteq\mathbb N$, it's easy to find a set $S$ of natural numbers that is not a rational number yet has $S\cap F=(x/y)\cap F$.  So this version of $\mathbb Q$ is not even $\Sigma_1^0$.

Comment: Are there more effective versions of $\mathbf{Q}$ which are $\Delta_1$?

Comment: If I were concerned about complexity, I'd define the (positive) rational numbers simply as (codes for) ordered pairs, like the $x;y$ in the question, such that $y\neq 0$ and such that $x$ and $y$ have no common divisor but 1. In other words, fractions in lowest terms (coded as natural numbers). If (unlike the definition you quoted) I also wanted to include negative rationals, I'd code in a sign along with the numerator and denominator. This coding makes $\mathbb Q$ a recursive set of natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I will consider this. I am just preparing a follow up question where I attempt to use the $\mu$-function. I link to that in these comments when I post it in a minute.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/264991/is-q-recursive

Comment: It is first of all important to me simply to know that $\mathbb{Q}$ can be had as a recursive set of natural numbers. Is there a standard reference, or is this simply folklore (obvious)?

Comment: There may be a reference, but I don't know one. I considered this obvious.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal if you want to see a standard development along the lines Andreas suggests, have a look at page 74 of Simpson's _Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic_.